# What's the appropriate HTTP response for invalid data submitted by the user?

Tags: php, javascript, json, http

I'm experimenting with JSON and http response codes. I'm submitting a form via an AJAX request and I obviously need to validate the data on the server-side.

My idea is to respond with a "200 OK" response (with a confirmation message as the body) if the post is successful. I don't know what to respond with if the data that the user sends is invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just implement a standard protocol like [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/).  It has error handling, parameter passing, etc.

Request:

```
{"method": "postMessage", "params": ["Hello all!"], "id": 99}
```

Response:

```
{"result": 1, "error": null, "id": 99}
```

And on error:

```
{"result": null, "error": "Duplicate Message", "id": 99}
```

It's quite flexible, and is **standard**...

Comment: Wow, even "standard" in *bold*.

Comment: :-D  It's a pet peeve of mine that people keep inventing their own protocols (and there are tons of major acclaim given to those that do).  Don't make your own unless an existing one really can't do what you need (and you're sure you need it)...

Comment: I'm not inventing my own protocol. My logic was that jQuery's $.ajax method can run different functions based upon the response code. So if there was an error response the returned message would be treated differently. But I accepted this answer as you're probably right that this is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 13):

You could send a `400: Bad Request` header. If that's not your cup of tea, maybe check through the [W3C's Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)?

Comment: If that's not your cup of tea: **418 I'm a teapot**

Answer (score 7):

Send back a JSON object:

```
$message = array(
   'error' => true,
   'code' => 'some error number relevant to you',
   'message' => 'A nice human-readable+relevant error message'
);

echo json_encode($message);
```

I prefer signaling errors with a service in this way. Fiddling with HTTP status codes doesn't seem right, as EVERYTHING about the actual HTTP request itself worked fine - it's just that the request didn't conform to the service's expectations.

Comment: +1: This is what I'd found when reading up on this exact same thing recently: HTTP status != user data status

Comment: Actually http status code 400 was intended for this, so it should "seem right". But it doesn't help developers much in case it is a public API.

Comment: Marc B - that's abusing HTTP as a tunnel. It's an application layer protocol, so 4xx is the right class of error.

Comment: Returning 404 for an ajax request on a record that doesn't exist in the DB is just wrong.... The ajax handler script is present and working, which is what the HTTP request was placed to. Returning an http 404 to say "no record found" implies that the ajax script itself was not found, which is not the case.

Comment: Marc B - nonsense. HTTP is about accessing resources. It totally doesn't matter how the server works internally. What matters is the resource identified by the HTTP URI, and the operation requested by the client.

Comment: Exactly. and ajax is layered on top of http. Using http status codes to signify ajax failures just confuses the issue. If you drive to the movies (http) but forget your wallet (ajax) so you can't even buy a ticket, do you blame http or ajax? Returning a 404 wallet not found is meaningless to the browser, as 404 means that http://movietheatre.com/ajax.php doesn't exist. it does not mean that `...ajax.php?wallet=50dollars` is not present.

Comment: @Marc: it means the resource is not found.  So it means the resource the identified by the URL (the wallet id) is not found.  So in this case, yes a 404 would be appropriate...

Comment: Marc B: The "x" in Ajax is for XHR. XHR is not layered on top of HTTP; it is an API for HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [complete list](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of HTTP status codes. The first one that springs to mind for your situation is 400 Bad Request, but that's usually used to indicate an error in the HTTP syntax rather than an error in the body content. Still, without more information I'd go with that one.

In specific cases, depending on the exact nature of the data you're receiving, I could see any of 403, 404, 410, 413, or perhaps others being the appropriate response.

Comment: The *complete* list of status codes is in the IANA registry: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the purpose of API. If it's yours (private) then answer with HTTP status 400 as Nightfirecat suggested. If it's a public API send a meaningful error message to aid developers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I typically see this done is that you let the HTTP response codes be used for things related to the HTTP protocol, not for your application errors.  Then, from your HTTP response, you return JSON that indicates success or failure and any desired returned data.  For example, you could return this:

```
{
    statusCode: 0,     // 0 = successful, negative value = error code
    statusMsg: "success",   // you can put any human readable status msg here
    data: {
        confirmationMsg: "Data sent successfully."
    }
}
```

Then, your code that looks at the response looks first at the statusCode and depending upon whether that is successful or not, it looks for other data.

If you imagine how this response will be used by the caller, I find it valuable to have different code paths for application level errors vs. transport level errors.  If you think about a `jQuery.ajax()` call.  The success handler will be called when the http status code is a successful code.  The error handler will be called when the http status code is not successful.  Doing it this way, you can have generic error handlers for all transport level errors with one ajax error handler and then you can put your specific application-level error handling in the success handler by examining the application level status code in the returned JSON.  If you go with the error 400, then you have to code up a whole different error handler for each ajax call to deal with both the transport errors and the application level errors.

Answer (score 0):

Either 400 (generic), or if you want to be more specific: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422